# Select matrix columns using vector of names

Tags: r, list

One list of names:

```
names = c(col1, col2, col6)
```

matrix like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
  1    4    5    2    7    2
  4    5    7    2    8    1
```

in order to have this:

```
col1 col2 col6
  1    4    2
  4    5    1
```

select "names" from "matrix" to create a new matrix.

Comment: `myMat[, names]` should do it. whether it is a matrix or a data.frame.

Comment: Regarding edit: no need to put tag in the title, and "thank you" is a noise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your names in quotes, then...

```
names = c("col1", "col2", "col6")
m2 <- m[,names]

m2
     col1 col2 col6
[1,]    1    4    2
[2,]    4    5    1
```